# Fabric: executing "systemctl status" on stopped process

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric, systemctl

I experience unexpected behavior with fabric 2.5 on Red Hat:

Executing 'systemctl status ' while the respective process is running, Fabric returns as expected:

```
>>> from fabric import Connection
>>> hostname = 'foo.bar'
>>> c = Connection(host=hostname, user=foo, connect_kwargs={"password":"bar",})
>>> result = c.sudo('systemctl status postgresql-9.6.service)
postgresql-9.6.service - PostgreSQL 9.6 database server
 Loaded: loaded(/usr    /lib ...)  ...
Active: active (running) since ...  ...
```

However, running the same on a process which is stopped, Fabric return with Exit code 3:

```
>>> result = c.sudo('systemctl stop postgresql-9.6.service)
>>> result = c.sudo('systemctl status postgresql-9.6.service)
postgresql-9.6.service - PostgreSQL 9.6 database server
 Loaded: loaded(/usr    /lib ...)  ...
Active: inactive (dead) since ...  ...
...
Traceback (most recent call list):
...
raise UnexpectedExit(result)
invoke.exceptions.UnexpectedExit: Encountered a bad command exit code!

Command: "sudo -S -p '[sudo] password: ' systemctl status postgresql-9.6.service"

Exit code: 3

Stdout: already printed

Stderr: n/a (PTYs have no stderr)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected.  status will return a non-zero error code for a stopped service.  To prevent this from raising an exception, add `warn=True` to the `sudo` call.